# Create a table structure in d3js from array of array and draw text or graph

Tags: d3.js

I have an array of array where each subarray represents a row in my table.
Each row has: 5 text elements, and the last element is an object.
For each row I have to print the 5 texts in 5 cells, and in the 6th cell I have to draw a svg graph depending on the object characteristics.

I'm using d3js for this, and I'm getting stuck about how to discriminate when to print text and when to print the svg. Here's the code:

```
d3.select(".main")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(newdata)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("row", true)
    .selectAll(".row")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("cell", true)
    .append("span")
    .classed("text", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

So for each row I create a div with class "row". Inside the row, I create a div for each cell with class "cell" and inside each of it I append a span with class "text" with the data text.

This works, but in the 6th cell I get of course the text representation of the object. In 6th cell of each row, I should not append span.text and print text but instead append a svg and begin to draw rectangles reading the object properties.

How should I do that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a selection of all the cells and then filter them based on the index in the row

```
var cells = d3.select(".main")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(newdata)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("row", true)
    .selectAll(".row")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("cell", true);

cells.filter( (d,i) => i <= 4 )
    .append("span")
    .classed("text", true)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

cells.filter( (d,i) => i === 5 )
    .append("svg");
```

Comment: @edoedoedo: instead of using the index you can check the type of `d` in the `filter` callback